# I can't get the user uid signed in in the rules of the firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here is my data.

```js
"users" : {
  "user1": {
    "1234": {
      "role": "admin"
    },
    "1235": {
      "role": "normal"
    }
  },
  "user2": {
    "1236": {
      "role": "admin"
    },
    "1237": {
      "role": "normal"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is rules for that.

```js
"rules" {
  "users": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child('user1').child(auth.uid).child('role') === 'admin'"
  }
}
```

But the rule doesn't work. I seem the auth.uid isn't gotten correctly.

Comment: what you are trying to do ?

Comment: As you can see, in the users, there are 2 types such as user1 and user2.
Each user type's admin can edit their user's role. And 1234, 1235 ... are user ids which got when sign up.

Comment: try to add `.val()` after `.child('role')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "user1": {
      "$user_id": {
           ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid && root.child('users/user1/' + $user_id + '/role/').val() === 'admin' "
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did, I missed .val() in above post. 
"rules": {
  "users": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child('user1').child('1234').child('role').val() === 'admin'"
  }
}

When I run above the rules, it works.
But if I use auth.uid instead of '1234', then it doesn't work. I seem the auth.id doesn't work correctly now. How can I get the current user id logined.

Comment: Yes, those ids are alphanumeric strings. For security, I wrote the ids as above.

Comment: Okay, I got you. In actual they are alphanumeric, it's just like you don't want to show those id's here. Right !

Comment: Yes, I checked it worked. but I need to get all users in both of user1 and user2 types. If I use your code, then I have some problem. In root/users, I had permission denied error.

Comment: Then, I think you should directly start with user id after users , don't include user1 and user2. That might solve your issue.
Because how a single user can have 2 different id's like you did for user1 - 1234 and 1235
Thanks !!!

Comment: I need the user role as well as user type. Don't you have good idea for that?

Comment: Okay, if you need both then add both these as child under same userID.
Like
"1234": {
   "role":  "admin"
   "type": "normal"
}